# Querying a Model Using an Array in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models, Question and Answer.

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
end
```

In my controller action, what I want to do is to determine all of the questions that a user has answered.  I have a query that finds all of the answers for a user:

```
@answers = current_user.answers
```

Now, I want to find out what Questions those relate to.  I tried

```
@questions = Question.where("id in ?", @answers)
```

but it doesn't work.  I get this error:

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '4,5,6)' at line 1: SELECT `questions`.* FROM `questions` WHERE (id in 4,5,6)
```

When I try this:

```
@questions = Question.where("id in ?", @answers.question_id)
```

I get this error (`question_id` is a field in Answer):

```
undefined method `question_id' for [4, 5, 6]:Array
```

How can I best query Questions based on Answers a User has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Question.where(id： @answers.map(&:question_id))`

Answer (score 1):

You can approach the problem from a different angle. You could have a custom scope in your `Question` model:

```
scope :by_answerer, -> (user_id) { includes(:answers).where(answers: {user_id: user_id}) }
```

Then in your `User` model:

```
def answered_questions
  Question.by_answerer(id)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in the SQL that is generated (in the error message)

```
SELECT `questions`.* FROM `questions` WHERE (id in 4,5,6)
```

that's not valid syntax. You want

```
SELECT `questions`.* FROM `questions` WHERE (id in (4,5,6))
```

so you're looking for

```
@questions = Question.where("id in (?)", @answers)
```